# Why I cannot open a CSV file using JQuery and FileContentResult

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make an ajax call (I specifically don't want to do it using ActionLink).

I'm having a controller that is like this:

```
public IActionResult ExportUsers(List<string> listOfEmails)
{
     /*some data processing*/
     return File(result, "text/csv", "ExportCandidates.csv");
}
```

On the other side with ajax I do this simple call:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Admin/Testcenter/GenerateInvitationPreview',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                    //some input data to send to the controller   ​
           ​},
           ​success: function (response) {
               ​)
           ​}
       ​});
```

I know there exists something for pdf files where you return a base64 file and with the response in the ajax call you just write something like pdfWindow.document.write(...) and this will open a new window with a pdf file.

Is there a way to extract the response for my CSV file and generate it so the user downloads it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
USE NPOI Library for Excel Sheet Generation  

  //Generate Excel Sheet
        try
                {
                    Guid gid = Guid.NewGuid();
                    string ext = ".xls";
                    string[] Headers = { "Appointments Id", "Date of Appointment", "Doctor Name", "Patient Name", "Visit Type", "Status" };
                    string fileName = "AppointmentsExcelSheet_" + gid.ToString() + ext;
                    var serverpath = _env.ContentRootPath;
                    string rootpath = serverpath + "/wwwroot/ExcelSheets/" + fileName;
                    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(rootpath, fileName));
                    var memorystream = new MemoryStream();
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(rootpath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
    
                        IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                        ISheet excelSheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Appointments List");
                        IRow row = excelSheet.CreateRow(0);
                        var font = workbook.CreateFont();
                        font.FontHeightInPoints = 11;
                        font.FontName = "Calibri";
                        font.Boldweight = (short)FontBoldWeight.Bold;
                        for (var i = 0; i < Headers.Length; i++)
                        {
                            var cell = row.CreateCell(i);
                            cell.SetCellValue(Headers[i]);
                            cell.CellStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
                            cell.CellStyle.SetFont(font);
                        }
    
                        var result = _Appointment.GetAppoinmentsPDf();
                        int index = 1;
                        foreach (var app in result.Items)
                        {
                            //var PatientDob = Convert.ToDouble(app.PatientDOB);
                            row = excelSheet.CreateRow(index);
                            row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(app.AppointmentId);
                            row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(app.DateofAppointment+" "+app.TimeofAppointment);
                            row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(app.DoctorFullName);
                            row.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue(app.SelectedPatientName);
                            row.CreateCell(4).SetCellValue(app.PurposeofVisit);
                            if (app.IsActive == false)
                            {
                                row.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue("Inactive");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                row.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue("Active");
                            }
                            index++;
                        }
                        workbook.Write(fs);
                    }
                    using (var filestream = new FileStream(rootpath, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        filestream.CopyToAsync(memorystream);
                    }
                    memorystream.Position = 0;
                    //send filepath to JQuery function
                    response.Msg = "/ExcelSheets/" + fileName;
    
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                  //exception code
                }
           return Ok(reponse.Msg)
    //JavaScript
    function AppointmentsExcelSheet() {
        //var token = Token;
        //var link = path;
        debugger
        $.ajax({
            //'Content-Type': 'application/pdf.',
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/Appointments/GetAppointmentsExcelSheet",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $.blockUI({
                    message: ('<img src="/images/FadingLines.gif"/>'),
                    css: {
                        backgroundColor: 'none',
                        border: '0',
                        'z-index': 'auto'
                    }
                });
            },
            complete: function () {
                $.unblockUI();
            },
           
            success: function (data) {
                debugger
                //downloads your Excel sheet
                window.location.href = data.msg;
                
            }
    
        });
    
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do what you want to do is to not use AJAX, but use either a link click that opens a new window (since you are passing in parameters) If you could use a

```
<form target="_blank">
```

to open a form response.  Inside the form can be a field or fields that contains the list of emails (it can be one field, or multiple input fields with the same name).  Your action handler can accept that list, parse it, and return a File response, and the natural result of opening the new window from the form post operation is a file that opens up.